# robot_localization performance with two IMU+GPS combinations

Tags: imu, robot-localization, gps, sensor-fusion

I use the same config file to compare the performance of two different IMU+GPS fusion for the same experiments. The performance of one pair of the IMU+GPS sensor fusion performs great when `odom0_differential` is set to true, but the other one produces really bad results.

When `odom0_differential` is set to false, both of them provide decent results in terms of state-estimation (not too good, not too bad).

Both the IMUs and GPSs aren't the same model, but are pretty close as per the documentation. I am having a hard time understanding why this might be the case. Attaching my config and launch files. I would really appreciate any help regarding this!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)....

Comment: In addition to what Greenonline said, please also include a sample message from each sensor input, and please do so as text.